# Use Data from SQLite Database to Create Buttons in Android

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have successfully implemented an SQLite database in my Android app insofar as I can add information using EditTexts, Spinners and RatingsBars and view that information in a ListView. The next step I am trying to implement is to turn the ListView into a list of buttons rather than just text. Essentially, I would like to be able to click on an element in the list and then be taken to a screen that lists that element's attributes - at the bottom, I would like to put two buttons: "Edit Entry" and "Delete Entry". How do I go about using the information from my SQLite database to dynamically populate the texts visible on buttons?

Comment: THis is not really a SQLite question is it, but has to do with the GUI.  Presumably you know how to select data from the database and get it into your client program in a structure where you can address individual values, and then do with those values what you will. I'd suggest you remove the SQLite tag unless your question is "How do I select data from SQlite and then address column values?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you will need to use buttons. You can implement the [OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html) interface from your Activity and detect when an item in the list was pressed and perform your actions there.

For populating the ListView from the database you will need to extend Android [CursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html).

If you really want to use buttons in your ListView you will need to extend [BaseAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) and in the adapter

```
   getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

place a button in the List Item. But I still think that using just the ListView and OnItemClickListener will solve your problem.

Comment: This sounds promising...I'm pretty new to Android (Writing my first app) so I'm still figuring out the basics. I'll definitely check this out - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use buttons you can add them in `getView()` method. You need to fetch the data store it `ArrayList`, feed this `ArrayList` to the `Adapter` you gonna use. Then the listview will populate. (This is how I imagine:) If you are fetching 3 words then 3 buttons must be number of buttons present in each item of the listview. Overlapping, might `scramble` the listview. At the button, you can inflate another layout with "Edit Entry" and "Delete Entry" everytime, item/button of the item is clicked. If you are displaying one piece from the SQL db in each item, there is no need for buttons `onItemClickedListener()` will do the work.